# Inserting multiple choice questions and answers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `Questions` and `Answers` which store the multiple choice question and the 4 possible answers, respectively. I am trying to insert one question along with its 4 answers at a time.

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint .... "dbo.Answers", column 'AnswerID'.

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint  table "dbo.Questions", column 'QuestionID'.
```

Here is what my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (    
    [QuestionID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [HistID]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [Question]   NCHAR (300)   NOT NULL,
    [AnswerID]   CHAR          NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (AnswerID) REFERENCES [dbo].Answers (AnswerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (HistID) REFERENCES [dbo].HistoricalEvents (HistID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers] (
    [QuestionID] INT         NOT NULL,
    [AnswerID]   CHAR        NOT NULL,
    [Choice]     NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestionID) REFERENCES [dbo].[Questions] (QuestionID), 
    PRIMARY KEY ([AnswerID])
);
```

These are the inserts I am trying:

```
INSERT INTO Questions (HistID, Question, AnswerID)
VALUES (
2,
'A major cause of the growth of state and Federal highway systems after World War II was the ___',
'C'
)

Declare @QuestionID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


INSERT INTO Answers(QuestionID, AnswerID, Choice)
VALUES 
(
@QuestionID,
'A',
'increased use of mass transit systems'
),

(
@QuestionID,
'B',
'growing prosperity of inner-city areas'
),

(
@QuestionID,
'C',
'rapid development of suburbs'
),

(
@QuestionID,
'D',
'return of city dwellers to farm areas'
)
```

***Expected output:***
I want the above command (or what it should change to) to make the following changes to the tables:

```
Questions:
QuestionID   HistID   Question                 AnswerID
--------------------------------------------------------
    1          2      "A major cause of the...    C     

Answers:
QuestionID   AnswerID   Choice
--------------------------------
    1          A         increased use of mass transit systems
    1          B         growing prosperity of inner-city areas
    1          C         rapid development of suburbs
    1          D         return of city dwellers to farm areas
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server, yes

Comment: instead of (Select Count()) you should use @@IDENTITY, or SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: but make sure you set it to a variable and use the variable in your Answers inserts... ` Declare @QuestionID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  then use @QuestionID

Comment: @JamieD77 Updated my OP to reflect the change

Comment: @JamieD77 - Since [`@@IDENTITY`] may return a value generated by a trigger it is best to avoid it. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` (or an `OUTPUT` clause) would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done what is called a cyclic reference. You have `Answers` as FK in Question and `Question` as FK in Answers Tables. Here you have placed contraints on both table of each other. So you can not insert neither because none of two exists during insert.

This should be:

> Question ---> Answers [QuestionId]FK only

Here's a hint to correct your schema:

Question Table -

```
+------------+
| QuestionId | (PK, int)
+------------+
| HistID     | (FK, int)
+------------+
| Question   | 
+------------+
```

AnswerTable (Available choices)-

```
+------------+
| AnswerId   | (PK, int)
+------------+
| Choice     | (char) -- A, B, C, D etc.
+------------+
| Answer     | (nvarchar(100)) -- limit depends on your choice
+------------+
| QuestionId | (FK, int) -- 1 to many relationship means 1 question can have multiple answers choice.
+------------+
```

Correct answer(choice) map table (Both FK will be composite key)-

```
+------------+
| AnswerId   | (FK, int)
+------------+            |--- composite primary key, 1-1 relationship means 1 question have only one correct choice.
| QuestionId | (FK, int)
+------------+
```

See - [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92f52/1) Showing the idea in implementation.

Comment: I understand that there should not be a cyclic reference, but I'm not sure how I can remove the reference, or create a Map table, as you say.

Comment: In the Question table, there is no need to have any reference to it's answers. The answer table, however, does need to know which Question it belongs to. Continuing along, the answer table does not need to know the correct answer. The mapping table will record what the correct answer is to each question. If you are asking HOW, then look at the Alter Table command.

Comment: @TysiaKrepps I have added sqlfiddle demo!! You can get the schema script from there.